# printing files based on character

Tags: python, pandas, linux, bash, numpy

I have a directory(`data`) that contain thousand of files.Each time I want to select `three` files that are just differ by only one character`AB[C,D,E]` and want to perform some computation on the selected three files later.

My files are present inside the directory as follows

```
DT.ABC.2007.182.144018.txt
DT.ABD.2007.182.144018.txt
DT.ABE.2007.182.144018.txt

DT.ABC.2001.005.1444.txt
DT.ABD.2001.005.1444.txt
DT.ABE.2001.005.1444.txt

DT.ABC.2003.005.1244.txt
DT.ABD.2003.005.1244.txt
DT.ABE.2003.005.1244.txt
```

and at first i want to print

```
    DT.ABC.2007.182.144018.txt
    DT.ABD.2007.182.144018.txt
    DT.ABE.2007.182.144018.txt
```

then

```
DT.ABC.2001.005.1444.txt
DT.ABD.2001.005.1444.txt
DT.ABE.2001.005.1444.txt
```

and same process would goes on until finishing reading all the files in the directory.

I tried the code below:

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('/data/*.txt'):
    print(st)
```

But it print all the files randomly instead of printing the same three(differ only by  `[C,D,E]` character.I hope experts may help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the prefix always the same as in the example? if so you could just extract the suffix and group by that

Comment: yes upto DT.AB? its always same

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: The real problem here is that your question is unclear, though. `glob` does not produce random results, it returns exactly the files which match the pattern you specify, in alphabetic order. If you want a more constrained pattern, you will need to specify that in the call (or perhaps add a condition around the `print` to skip the ones you don't want if articulating a glob pattern for what you want is more complex than simple glob patterns allow).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function which lists files and groups them by the first and third component of the file name.

```py
def groupfiles(pattern):
    files = glob.glob(pattern)
    filedict = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        parts = file.split(".")
        filedict[".".join([parts[0], parts[2]])].append(file)
    for filegroup in filedict.values():
        yield filegroup
```

This groups together and returns a list of files at a time (`yield` is a keyword which produces a generator; but you can think of it as a sort of replacement for `return`, only the function continues where it left off after the previous call instead of running from the start the next time you call it) and so does not hard-code the limit of three files at a time.

Demo: https://ideone.com/w2Sf80

Comment: no it just print all files , my files are saved in a directory. Files are not separated by groups.

Comment: The demo works with the names you gave as examples. If your real files have different names, please do share them.

Comment: ok how to share can you please send some link

Comment: The last line of the answer is a link to the demo. You can easily fork it and populate it with different file names, and share the link back here in a comment if you like.

Comment: I am not going to download some random zip file. Show me a few of your actual file names.

Comment: CB.NJ2.00.BHE.M.2014.200.122716.txt
CB.NJ2.00.BHE.M.2014.268.091354.txt
CB.NJ2.00.BHN.M.2014.200.122716.txt
CB.NJ2.00.BHN.M.2014.268.091354.txt
CB.NJ2.00.BHZ.M.2014.200.122716.txt
CB.NJ2.00.BHZ.M.2014.268.091354.txt

Comment: i need to print CB.NJ2.00.BHE.M.2014.200.122716.txt  CB.NJ2.00.BHN.M.2014.200.122716.txt CB.NJ2.00.BHN.M.2014.200.122716.txt should be printed first

Comment: Those look like they should all be in the same set, is that correct? Not a good test case though. Demo: https://ideone.com/tPsg1N

Comment: What's the principle for how they should be sorted?

Comment: yes all are in a directory and i want to print three file at a time

Comment: 200.122716 portion of three files should match then three files should be printed

Comment: So like this? They are not in the order you stipulated but that should be easy to fix if you can explain the principle. I changed this to pull the eight and ninth fields between dots as the  grouping key. https://ideone.com/Ay3yC9

Comment: I mean first i want to print three files with matching pattern and want to apply some operation on it then i want to jump next three files ...

Comment: That's what this does; you call the function, it gives you three files. You call it again, it gives you three more.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, please try to state your requirements up front.

Comment: its taking one by one file only...suppose i want to plot these three files at once...it plots one by one

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the function returns a list of files with each call. If the grouping criteria are still wrong, some groups could contain only one file. If you want to force it to ignore groups altogether, just make it always return the next three in each `yield`, but that seems to violate your stated criteria. Perhaps post a new question with more details if you can't figure it out.

Comment: ok...it actually fetch three files at a time but while applying some process on it it process one file each time instead of three...

Comment: always return the next three in each yield how to do can you please update once the code.

Comment: Basically `for i in range(0, len(files), 3): yield files[idx:idx+3]`

Comment: sir where to add this line is it after yield filegroup

Comment: getting error like NameError: name 'idx' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, replace `i` with `idx`. This would replace the more complex function entirely.

Comment: after changing i am getting random files printed....please update sir

Comment: Again, if you have a new question, _ask_ a new question with your requirements, in enough detail for someone to understand how to generalize from your examples. If you are unfamiliar with basic Python syntax, don't change things you don't have to change in the examples. And don't move the goalposts by piling on new requirements in comments.

Comment: They are not "random", they are sorted alphabetically. If you want a different sort order, `sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.split('.')[7:8])` sorts by the eighth and ninth fields. period-separated.

Comment: quite difficult for me to understand if possible please updae