# read data group wise with certain pattern

Tags: python, for-loop, glob

i have data inside a directory as follows

```
 IU.WRT.00.MTR.1999.081.081015.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTS.2007.229.022240.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTR.2007.229.022240.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTT.1999.081.081015.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTS.1999.081.081015.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTT.2007.229.022240.txt
```

and i want to read data group wise,

At first I want to read 3 files with similar pattern (differ by R,S,T)

```
IU.WRT.00.MTR.1999.081.081015.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTS.1999.081.081015.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTT.1999.081.081015.txt
```

and want to apply some operations on it

and then i want to read data

```
IU.WRT.00.MTT.2007.229.022240.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTS.2007.229.022240.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTR.2007.229.022240.txt
```

and want to apply similar operation on it.

In the sameway i want to continue the process for millions of data sets.

I tried the example script

```
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

def groupfiles(pattern):
    files = glob.glob(pattern)
    filedict = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        parts = file.split(".")
        filedict[".".join([parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]])].append(file)
    for filegroup in filedict.values():
        yield filegroup
 
for relatedfiles in groupfiles('*.txt'):
    print(relatedfiles)

    for filename in relatedfiles:
        print(filename)
```

However it reads the file one by one but i need to read 3 file at a time.I hope experts may help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by reading 3 files at a time? Do you mean reading 3 txt files parallelly in threads?

Comment: yes sir @Vishnudev ...but with pattern matching as given

Comment: The pattern should be `IU.WRT.00.MT[RST].1999.081.081015.txt` for the first set and please don't address as "sir" XD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236960/discussion-between-chumun-b-and-vishnudev).

Comment: Sock puppet, previous question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100209/printing-files-based-on-character

Comment: @tripleee...actually your answer didnot solve my problem  and my account got blocked so i took the help from my friends account. Can you suggest how to assign first three files to a variable and then next three files

Answer (score 2):

Use proper patterns to get the files

```
files_1999 = glob.glob('IU.WRT.00.MT[RST].1999.081.081015.txt')
```

To generalize,

```
years = set(file.split('.')[4] for file in glob.glob('*.txt'))
file_group = {}

for year in years:
    pattern = f'IU.WRT.00.MT[RST].{year}*.txt'
    file_group[year] = glob.glob(pattern)
```

Output

```
{
   "2007":[
      "IU.WRT.00.MTS.2007.229.022240.txt",
      "IU.WRT.00.MTR.2007.229.022240.txt",
      "IU.WRT.00.MTT.2007.229.022240.txt"
   ],
   "1999":[
      "IU.WRT.00.MTS.1999.081.081015.txt",
      "IU.WRT.00.MTR.1999.081.081015.txt",
      "IU.WRT.00.MTT.1999.081.081015.txt"
   ]
}
```

Comment: I want to automate the year also...its not possible to write the year for millions of file...for example data set its fine.can you please suggest how to do it for millions of file

Comment: it doesnot give data group wise as i  explained in the question

Comment: some error defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1999: [], 2007: []})

Comment: Check now. @chumunB

Comment: Actually it gives me dictionary ... i need 3 files to be printed  and then next three files

Comment: how can i add something like np.arange to read three files then another 3 files

Comment: Do you mean, the content to be read and printed?

Comment: yes @Vishnudev ..u r right...each three should be read at a time not one by one

Comment: That shifts the context of the question a lot. So, ask another question just for reading multiple files parallelly.

Comment: i got blocked...if possible please add this line sir...